# Exchange user gets email from other user on behalf BUG

Tags: exchange-server-2010

I have a wired problem on my Exchange 2010 server, original migrated from af 2007.

I have a mailbox: user1@domain

For one of our meetingroom I gave this:

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "meetingroom1:\calendar" -User "user1" -AccessRights "PublishingEditor"
```

When 'user1' book a meeting directly in 'meetingroom1' calendar and invite some user e.g. 'user2', then 'user3' receive a meeting request from 'user1' on behalf of 'meetingroom1'

I don't get why 'user3' is involved in this???
I have checked the 'user3' is not Delegate for the Meetingroom and a lot of other stuff.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:
http://exchangeserverpro.com/deleted-delegates-still-receive-meeting-invites-for-other-mailbox-users/

Really nice guide!